# Visual Studio 2010 crashes every 2 minutes on windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio

I'm running visual studio 2010 on windows 7 RC, and it crashed almost anytime I hit F5 to start the application.

also when using the XAML WPF editor, if I don't hold and wait for it more than 30 seconds to switch from the design to the XAML code it crashes also!

by the way I Visual Studio 2008 worked perfectly on the same laptop with Win7 beta!

Does anyone ecountred this issue and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Well VS2010 is still in beta *and* you are using an OS version that's not *quite* finished. I suggest you report it on some kind of VS2010 beta forum.

Comment: While I've not done any substantial projects yet, I've only seen it crash due to a known issue with the WF designer being locked to the default install directory (addition of a hard link fixes that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look and I couldn't see the bug logged at [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com)

You should log the bug with Microsoft. This is a link to a search query with all the Visual Studio bugs that have been logged on connect with the terms crash and 2010
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=+2010+crash

You will probably need to log in with a live id to see the results.

Comment: You've missed a `]` for the first link